# About iOS development process send game's an ".app" file for test

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios-provisioning

I'm an officially iOS developer. My designer lives in different City and I would like to know: Can I send our game's an ".app" file to him to install on his iPhones for test through the iTunes? He doesn't know xCode, only designers programs and lives far from me. I can add his iPhones in "Devices" on "Provisioning Portal"

Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a build(.ipa) and send it to him so that he installs it and sees what does the app do.

The other(easier in my opinion) option is to use one of the websites that offer easy testing. One of them is [testflightapp](http://www.testflightapp.com). Register there, send invitation to your designer and then just upload a build. It will then be available for both of you(and other people if you added them). Just open the link that you will get in an email and install the app

Comment: +1, but remember that you'll need to add you designer's device ID to the devices in your developer account for him to be able to install it on his device.

Comment: where I can find this .ipa file?

Comment: @AlexanderSharunov did you ever make a build before? Just like Bernd said in his post: `Archive your app Xcode menu/Product/Archive (it becomes available when select iOS as target)`

Answer (score 2):

No Alexander. You can't send the .app file. Make sure you signed your app with an adhoc provisioning profile where your designers iOS device is listed. Archive your app Xcode menu/Product/Archive (it becomes available when select iOS as target). Then go to the Organizer/Archives and distribute it. XCode will save it as .ipa file. This file you should send to your designer. He/she can drop it onto iTunes and sync it to the device.

Comment: where I can find this .ipa file?

Comment: Once you have found your app in the side bar (Organizer/Archives) press the distribute button and select "save for enterprise or Ad-Hoc deployment. Select your code signing identity (the one you created for adhoc deployment). Once your app is signed you are presented by a file save dialog. Choose the place where you want it to be and you are done. If you interested and more experienced check out on github hockeykit. It give you a way of over the air distribution.